# Login info is shown is plain text on Nginx and php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, codeigniter-4, fpm

I am using code igniter 4 with php-fpm and Nginx. For some reason I get ini_set() error with header already sent information occasionally. When the error happens I see login information and url in plain text on the screen.

Can someone please tell me more about what is causing the issue?

Comment: Could you please provide a code example? no pictures and a description of the response.

Comment: This is the error message : CRITICAL - 2020-10-15 06:34:46 --> ini_set(): Headers already sent. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time
But this happens occasionally and not always. This happens after few days and I have to restart docker containers.
And when this happens I see all the url with post parameters on the screen.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

add `ob_start();` to the top of your index.php file in the project root directory. I believe that should help!